# gurobi is installed but Matlab doesn't recognize it

Tags: linux, matlab, gurobi

Matlab16, Linux 16.04, Gurobi 6.5.2

I want to use Cobra toolobox on Matlab, so I installed it and Gurobi as asked too.
But when I try this code (as explain in an research article : What is FBA ? Orth, Palsson) I got an error

The code

`model = readCbModel('ecoli_core_model.xml')
optimizeCbModel(model)`

The error

`Error using solveCobraLP (line 107)
No solver found.  call changeCobraSolver(solverName)

Error in optimizeCbModel (line 213)
    solution = solveCobraLP(LPproblem);
`

In changeCobraSolver.m, it said that Gurobi is a right solver. Apparently, Matlab and Gurobi are not connected.

I added `.../gurobi652/linux64/matlab` to the path and I tried (as explain here http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/matlab_setting_up_the_guro.html) a function. I worked.

I tried to install Gurobi Mex (here http://www.convexoptimization.com/wikimization/index.php/Gurobi_Mex:_A_MATLAB_interface_for_Gurobi) but I don't find Gurobi_mex.c

Yesterday `optimizeCbModel` worked but I don't know what I did and what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that, if I try `testAll` then `optimizeCbModel` succeed (no error at least). I think we need to do `initCobraToolbox` first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are in CobraToolbox folder in MATLAB directory first. Call initCobraToolbox
2. changeCobraSolver ('gurobi', 'all')
3. Both read and optimize functions should be able to be used now.

You may find it easier to use .mat files for input model. These can be found under cobratoolbox --> test --> models --> mat

Hope this helps